# How does ValidateAntiForgeryToken fit with Web APIs that can be accessed via web or native app?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, antiforgerytoken

I'm trying to understand how I will be able to craft an API using ASP.NET Web API which will be protected from [CSRF](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-%28csrf%29-attacks), while still being accessible from non-web environments (e.g. native mobile applications).

My first thought would be that a non-web environment can never successfully pass an anti-forgery token validation, since it doesn't have a form that is posted.  Is this true?  Is there any way to make validation work?

If there isn't a way to validate, my second thought is to offer an API which validates anti-forgery tokens for web calls but not for non-web calls.  However, it seems like an attacker would just as easily be able to use this "non-web" API for a CRSF attack, right?

Is the answer that the non-web API needs to only support a non-web authentication mechanism (OAuth?), so that requests to it cannot be replayed via a browser?  Or is there a simpler way?

If that's the only way, is there an easy way to turn off all of the insecure authentication mechanisms?  Shouldn't there be a somewhat simple/happy path in ASP.NET Web API to support these scenarios?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSRF only becomes a problem when you are using a persistent auth mechanism such as cookies, basic auth, NTLM etc. Mike Wasson has [an example](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-%28csrf%29-attacks) of using CSRF against webapi in Javascript - and I've seen versions in DelegatingHandlers ....

As CSRF is only a problem in web scenarios you can argue there's no real need to check for non-web requests. Every ajax request from a browser, whether via jquery, the native XmlHttpRequest classes or whatever comes with a header - X-Requested-With, which will have a value of XMLHttpRequest. So you could limit your CSRF checks to just requests with that header, as anything without it must have come from outside a browser.

*Having said that if you are authenticating, I'd look at some sort of shared secret or OAuth mechanism, and have a DelegatingHandler server side to validate, and in the web app just put the token somewhere that it can be picked up via javascript and sent via an X-Authentication header - as it's not persistent and needs to be attached to every request (just like the CSRF token) there's no CSRF problems. Dominick, as ever, [documents](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/wiki) this sort of thing well.*

Comment: as far as I'm aware "X-Requested-With" headers are not put in the request nativly, only by frameworks like jquery

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the SPA templates in the latest MVC4 update. They have a sample implementation for Anti-CSRF for Web API.

Comment: I already have an anti-CSRF implementation (via the DotNetNuke Services Framework), I'm just trying to understand how/if it works with native apps.  I don't see anything in the SPA template that would enable their APIs to work if there's no AJAX or form POST.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the CORS implementation for WebAPI.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/07/02/cors-support-in-asp-net-web-api-rc-version.aspx

Then you could allow only localhost as a valid URI on the webapi server.  This would prevent other sites from loading attack code in the browser.

Comment: Restricting to localhost doesn't seem to help with a native mobile application, right?

Comment: Well I was using phonegap, which was running locally on the client.