# ASP.NET Web API - Passing a UserToken(string) to a LoginController using a DelegatingHandler

Tags: delegates, asp.net-web-api, httphandler

I have an ASP.NET Web API project and on initial user login, the username and password are sent in an http header over SSL and validated by the server.

The server creates a database record with the UserId, a randmon 64 character string (UserToken), expiration date and the client IP address.

The UserToken is then sent back to the client and then be stored in a cookie.

All subsequent requests send the UserToken in an http header and that is validated using the calling IP address by the server.

This way, the username and password are only sent once, and all calls using the UserToken are logged.

I have created two custom DelegatingHandlers - LoginAuthenticationHandler, and TokenAuthenticationHandler - which process the http headers and send an appropriate 200 or 400 http response.

////////////////

Seems my only problem is that I want the LoginAuthenticationHandler to also return the UserToken to the client, so it can store the cookie.

Sorry for the verbosity :-\

Also - I'm new to Web API - so maybe this is not the best place for this to be done - but it would be very convenient if the UserToken can be passed back to the LoginController in this way.

Thanks for any input :-)

Some related SO posts:

[DelegatingHandler for response in WebApi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970313/delegatinghandler-for-response-in-webapi)

[Is it possible to pass data from DelegatingHandler to Controller in ASP.NET Web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16418632/is-it-possible-to-pass-data-from-delegatinghandler-to-controller-in-asp-net-web)

////////////////

```
  public class LoginAuthenticationHandler : DelegatingHandler
      {
          public const string BasicScheme = "Basic";
          public const string ChallengeAuthenticationHeaderName = "WWW-Authenticate";
          public const char AuthorizationHeaderSeparator = ':';

          protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
              HttpRequestMessage request,
              CancellationToken cancellationToken)
          {
              // Get Authorization Http Header
              var authHeader = request.Headers.Authorization;
              if (authHeader == null)
              {
                  // Unauthorized
                  return CreateUnauthorizedResponse();
              }
              // Check if Basic Authentication
              if (authHeader.Scheme != BasicScheme)
              {
                  // Unauthorized
                  return CreateUnauthorizedResponse();
              }
              // Decode UserName + Password from Http Header
              var encodedCredentials = authHeader.Parameter;
              var credentialBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedCredentials);
              var credentials = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(credentialBytes);
              var credentialParts = credentials.Split(AuthorizationHeaderSeparator);
              if (credentialParts.Length != 2)
              {
                  // Unauthorized
                  return CreateUnauthorizedResponse();
              }
              var username = credentialParts[0].Trim();
              var password = credentialParts[1].Trim();
              // Authenticate Username + Password and Return UserToken
              var userId = new Users().GetUserIdFromUserNamePassword(username, password);
              if (userId == 0)
              {
                  // Unauthorized
                  return CreateUnauthorizedResponse();
              }
              // User is Authorized - Create New UserToken
              var ipAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
              var userToken = new Users().CreateUserToken(ipAddress, userId);

              return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(task =>
                  {
                      var response = task.Result;
             //======================================================
             // Return UserToken to Login Controller to be Stored as Cookie on the Client
                      // response.Content = userToken ??
                      // maybe set header for userToken ??
                      // HttpRequestMessage Properties ??
                      return response;
             //======================================================
                  });
          }

          private static Task<HttpResponseMessage> CreateUnauthorizedResponse()
          {
              // Send Back Http Unauthorized if Authentication Fails
              var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
              response.Headers.Add(ChallengeAuthenticationHeaderName, BasicScheme);
              var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();
              taskCompletionSource.SetResult(response);
              return taskCompletionSource.Task;
          }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, HTTP services are stateless and the concept of login does not apply. LoginController is for the MVC controllers and not web API. What you are trying to do is not a good practice, even though it is technically possible to achieve.

If you really want to do what you are trying to do, do not think along the lines of sending the session data (what you call the user token) to LoginController. You can write the cookie into the response from your message handler itself. See [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/http-cookies). You must only store encrypted data into a cookie in that case. Instead of creating your own cookie and all that, you can use Forms Authentication and create a cookie with FA ticket. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.aspx).

BTW, it is possible and easy to spoof client IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could login using the controller *without* using a DelegatingHandler:  you could return the token to the client to be added to the header of future API calls, or add it to the header in the controller using the Request.Headers.Add function.

Then you would not need two custom DelegatingHandlers, the TokenAuthenticationHandler would be sufficient.  But you would want to specify that all requests *other than* the initial login are funneled through the TokenAuthenticationHandler.

To do that, you will need to customize the WebAPI routes.  In the default Web API projects, this is currently done in the WebApiConfig.Register method in WebApiConfig.cs (called from Global.asax.cs).  First, have all your API calls route through your TokenAuthenticationHandler; then add the login route plainly such that it does *not* funnel through your TokenAuthenticationHandler:

```
//this message handler chain is used to put TokenAuthenticationHandleron all API requests and not Login
DelegatingHandler[] handlers = new DelegatingHandler[] {
    new TokenAuthenticationHandler()
};
var routeHandlers = HttpClientFactory.CreatePipeline(new HttpControllerDispatcher(config), handlers);
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: null,
    constraints: null,
    handler: routeHandlers
 );

//login route
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Login",
    routeTemplate: "login/{action}",
    defaults: new { Controller = "Login" }
);
```

Now, you can validate the token in the TokenAuthenticationHandler using request.Headers.TryGetValues to get it:

```
protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    //token validation
    IEnumerable<string> foundValues = null;
    if (request.Headers.TryGetValues("AuthenticationToken", out foundValues))
    {
        if (foundValues.Count() == 1)
        {
            string token = foundValues.Single();

            AuthenticationDAO dao = new AuthenticationDAO();
            if (dao.AuthenticateUser(token))
            {
                //add values to request.Properties for use in Web API controllers
                request.Properties.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("SomeValue", 4));

                //Engage!
                return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            }
        }
    }

    //fail if token not present or not valid
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();
    tcs.SetResult(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
    {
        Content = new StringContent("Missing or invalid authorization token.")
    });
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

As per your original question of passing values from the DelegatingHandler to the Controller, that is easily possible using the request.Properties.Add function as demonstrated above.

Some additional considerations:

- I am not sure that sending the login credentials in the header is any
  more secure than just as content in the request, since it is all over
  SSL.
- You should consider implementing an AntiForgeryToken.  [This
  article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-%28csrf%29-attacks) is a good starter, and [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755607/how-does-validateantiforgerytoken-fit-with-web-apis-that-can-be-accessed-via-web) points out how
  you could use DelegatingHandler to also only check for it on web
  requests (allowing your api to be accessed from native apps).
- You can easily add a DelegatingHandler that applies to *all* requests
  that enforces HTTPS.

Hope that helps.  What I've outlined is the way I'm doing it, so I hope for some comments if it's wrong.